# Python 3 Error ( on my open list) Only returning three items

Tags: python, list, for-loop, error-handling, while-loop

Hello I am having an error running my horse race program. Essentially I just want to type in names on the last part and it should make a horse for each name. Once the user types XXX the naming stops and the race begins. Any Help will do. I will show you how the program runs.

My error is only at part E

```
import random

print ("Random number from 10-21 is : " )
print (random.randrange(10,21))


##get the average
def average(times):
 return sum(times) / len(times)


times = []
counter = 0

while counter < (1001):
 counter += 1
 times.append(random.randrange(10,21))

print (average(times))


## for one horse in the race
distance = 0
seconds = 1
while distance <= 10560:

 distance += (random.randrange(4,41))
 seconds += 1
print(distance)

##one horse running 1000 races 
seconds = 0
distance = 0
times = []
counter = 0

while counter < (1001):
 counter += 1
 while distance <= 10560:
  num = (random.randrange(4,41))
  distance += num
  seconds += 1
  times.append(seconds)

print("Part C, Average of horses time", average(times))
##function that adds the random distance the horse
def horse(x):
 b = random.randrange(4,41)
 x = x + b
 return x

##Part  D
number_of_ = int(input("How many horses are in the race: "))
distance = []
for i in range(number_of_):
 distance.append(0)
finishline = True
print(distance)
while finishline:
 for p in range(len(distance)):
  distance[p] = horse(distance[p])
 if max(distance) <= 10560:
  finishline = True
 else:
  finishline = False
print(distance)
print("The winner is" , max(distance))
#part E
name_of_horses = []
distance_of_horses = []
STOP = "XXX" 
names = input("Enter a name for each horse: ")
while names != STOP:
    name_of_horses.append(names)
    names = input("Enter a name for each horse: ")

for i in range(len(names)):
 distance_of_horses.append(0)
finishline = True
print(name_of_horses)
while finishline:
 for p in range(len(distance_of_horses)):
  distance_of_horses[p] = horse(distance_of_horses[p])

 if max(distance_of_horses) <= 10560:
  finishline = True
 else:
  finishline = False
print(distance_of_horses)
print("The winner is" , max(distance_of_horses))
```

Provided down below is what the program currently return. I know I am a noob but any help will do. Thank you.

```
==================
Random number from 10-21 is : 
11
15.036963036963037
10567
Part C, Average of horses time 245.0
How many horses are in the race: 5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[10588, 10532, 10444, 10461, 10362]
The winner is 10588
Enter a name for each horse: dom
Enter a name for each horse: dom
Enter a name for each horse: dom
Enter a name for each horse: dom
Enter a name for each horse: dom
Enter a name for each horse: dom
Enter a name for each horse: XXX
['dom', 'dom', 'dom', 'dom', 'dom', 'dom']
[10477, 10574, 10251]
The winner is 10574
```

Comment: I don't get it, what's the error?

Comment: The lists input was five names but it only gives back three numbers

Comment: for i in range(len(names)): it should be len(name_of_horses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem lies on line 78

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    distance_of_horses.append(0)
```

since the **names** read by your program is treated as string (and string is an array of chars) it will treat your string as array of chars, in this case "XXX" is 3 chars, so your distance_of_horses will of course have 3 values in it

Classic mistyping error

Note: I don't think this should be in answer section, but I'm not allowed to comment yet